# Using Input box to enter folder path and store it as a variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code to loop through files in a folder and spit it out on an excel spreadsheet, which does work fine if I manipulate the portion that says "C:\VBA Folder".

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles ()

Dim oFSO As Object
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim oFile As Object
Dim i As Integer

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("C:\VBA Folder")

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files

    Cells(i + 1, 1) = oFile.Name

    i = i + 1

Next oFile

End Sub
```

What I would like to do is manipulate it so that an input box would come up and ask me for the path and automatically substitute C:\VBA Folder with my input, so I coded it like this:

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()

Dim oFSO As Object
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim oFile As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim FolderPath As String

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

FolderPath = InputBox("Enter Path")

Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("FolderPath")

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files

    Cells(i + 1, 1) = oFile.Name

    i = i + 1

Next oFile

End Sub
```

The above code results in a "Run Time Error 76: Path not found", even though the path does exist and the path does work if I manually input it in the first snippet of code:

Can someone please try to provide a suggestion of where I am wrong?

Comment: `oFSO.GetFolder("FolderPath")` remove the quotes?

Comment: `FolderPath = InputBox("Enter Path", Default:="C:\VBA Folder")` (in addition to the comment above)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the built in [FileDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.filedialog) to select a folder. The following function will return the path

```
Function selectFolder(Optional initialDir As String) As String

    Dim fld As FileDialog
    
    Set fld = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fld
        .InitialFileName = initialDir
        If .Show = False Then
            selectFolder = ""
        Else
            selectFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
    
End Function
```

In your code you could use it like that

```
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(selectFolder("C:\VBA Folder"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to modify the code to suit you:

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
Dim oFSO As Object
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim oFile As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim FolderPath As String

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

RETRY:
FolderPath = InputBox("Enter Path")
    If StrPtr(FolderPath) = 0 Then ' USER CANCELLED INPUTBOX
        MsgBox "User cancelled"
    ElseIf oFSO.FolderExists(FolderPath) Then ' IF FOLDER EXISTS DO IT
        Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(FolderPath)
        For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
            Cells(i + 1, 1) = oFile.Name
            i = i + 1
        Next oFile
    Else '  FOLDER DOES NOT EXISTS
        MsgBox FolderPath & " does not exist!"
        GoTo RETRY
    End If
End Sub
```